# Customizing/theming a created view

Tags: views, theming

I searched a lot on net, but did not find proper answer for the customizing / theming  a view that is created. I have created a view like one in screenshot[image] . I wanted to change the way the pagination appears and some cosmetic changes for it. So whats the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unformatted style, instead of the table style. Then use CSS in your theme and you can style it any way you want. Should you want to change the html (I hardly ever need it), try rearranging the view or using the [suggested templates](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/drupal-6-views-templates-544.html).